# Record video from stream, audio from USB device and mix then together

Tags: sound, video, alsa, ffmpeg

I need to record a video stream and mix it with audio from external device (USB sound card).
I managed to record the video and audio separately with following commands.

Video
`ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.0.192  -acodec copy -vcodec copy ~/out.mp4`

Audio
`ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:1 -t 30 out.wav`

Now I need to record both at the same time and create an mp4 file.

I tried this command, but it gives me an error.

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:1 -i rtsp://192.168.0.192  -acodec copy -vcodec copy ~/out.mp4

Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

EDIT: Using mkv container instead of mp4 works. How should I encode the video to be able to store it as mp4?

Comment: Not really sure which audio stream you want to record (from the video or from the audio input)? There is no information about the audio codec for the audio stream; in the separate record `wav`is implicit from the extension of the output file. Try to use `map` and explicit audio codec.

Answer (score 0):

MP4 doesn't support PCM audio (the format family commonly found in WAV files).

The console output indicates this immediately above the line you showed, but you omitted it:

```
[mp4 @ 0x559e59ef2360] Could not find tag for codec pcm_s16le in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
```

You options are:

- Output to a different output container format, such as .mov or Matroska (.mkv) as you already discovered, or
- Encode the audio to a format supported by MP4, such as AAC, by replacing `-acodec copy` with `-c:a aac`.